# Notepad++ Search For 3 Character

Tags: notepad++

I have a huge textfile with different names. How do I search for names that only include 3 characters or are three characters long?

Comment: Do you have a sample of the text file? Is it *only* names? If so, use regex.

Comment: Yeah but what should i use in the regex im trying \w\w\w but won work

Comment: What characters are allowed and what aren't? Please show some example with expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press Ctrl+F and enable Regular expression search.
Now search for:

```
[^A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]
```

It'll basically search for:

```
[Non-letter character] 3*[letter character] [Non-letter character]
```

EDIT:
As you said, you wanted to search for numbers too, so this is how:

```
[^A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]
```

Comment: How do I include numbers

Comment: I think you add 1-9 after every a-z, like [^A-Za-z1-9][A-Za-z1-9][A-Za-z1-9][A-Za-z1-9][^A-Za-z1-9]

Comment: @user2227874 Not very sure, though